# Use react router actions with json data

Tags: reactjs, json, react-router, form-data

I have this Form where I create an object of this structure from the users input:

```js
interface FormValues {
  amount: number
  expense: boolean
  categories: {
    amount: number
    category_id: number
  }[]
}
```

To post that to the backend I could just use the fetch API in this fashion:

```js
fetch('/api/transactions/add', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(values),
})
```

But this doesn't feel like how React Router wants me to do it. Which would bother me less if there wasn't the problem of React Router not automatically revalidating the data that's displayed in the frontend.

Instead React Router has these ideas in mind, which guarantee a revalidation of all your loaded data displayed in the frontend after submitting:

```js
// forms
<Form method="post" action="/transactions/add" />;
<fetcher.Form method="put" action="/transactions/add" />;
// or after some logic
fetcher.submit(formData, options);
```

with the action defined in such fashion:

```js
<Route
  path="/transactions/add"
  element={<AddSong />}
  action={async ({ params, request }) => {
    let formData = await request.formData();
    return fetch('/api/transactions/add', {
      method: 'post',
      body: formData,
    });
  }}
/>
```

The issue is that FormData is restricted to `(key: string, value: string)` pairs. Hence I'd like to just send the json object as above given the structure of the form values I have. On top of that it's easier to handle in the backend too if it's json.

Why does React Router restrict me to the formData type when submitting requests?

Comment: There's absolutely ***nothing*** forcing you to use `react-router-dom` to make your fetch requests and validate any data. It's just another tool in the toolset of running a React application. You can use raw `fetch`, `axios` calls, redux-thunks, etc.

Comment: @DrewReese How would you recommend automatically reloading all displayed data after the post request that I did, say, simply with fetch? I don't want to have to reload the site when I have the entire site running with client side routing.

Comment: I suppose that depends on where and how you are storing the data, and what response values are. Does the PUT endpoint return the entire data with the update merged? Can you just optimistically update the client state? Are you using request management like GraphQL or Redux-Toolkit-Query? There are many options to choose from, and since we can only see one single `fetch` making a PUT request and know nothing else about your app/state it's difficult for anyone here to make a sound recommendation.

Comment: I'm displaying a list of transactions, retrieved by the loader function of the route. Then in a modal there is said form, which submits a request adding a new transaction. If I use react routers way of submitting, it automatically reloads the data from said loader function, but doesn't if i use the fetch api.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old by now, but since I ran across it...

You can specify an enctype="application/json" on your form or in your `fetcher.submit()` call. You can then call `data = await request.json()` to extract it from the request.